# How to change locale from application in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react native app that supports both English & Spanish locale. How to change locale from my app?

Any advice or solution ? :/

Thank you.

Comment: Which component are you using? Did you check [react-native-localization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization)?

Comment: @milkersarac. I'm looking for component to do it. How can I change locale with your library? What method should I use?

Comment: You should read the README thoroughly, but there is a method called `setLanguage(languageCode)` - to force manually a particular language.